# ValueError: invalid literal for int() after reading input into a tuple

Tags: python-3.x, list, tuples

I am writing a code that takes some numbers as tuple and then verify if there are numbers divisible by 3.

I am a beginner in python and just know some basic stuff about tuples. I have my code below:

```
def Div3and5():
    data=tuple(input("Enter 3 numbers:"))
    c=[]
    a=0
    for i in range(0,len(data)):
        d=data[i]
        c.append(d)
    m=[int(x) for x in c]
    print(m)
    for i in m:
        if m[i]%3==0:
           print("It is not divisible")
Div3and5()
```

So, when I run this code I get an error which is:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ','
```

See, the values are stored as integers and when I give a command of printing `c`, it clearly shows all elements. Then, I try to convert each element to integers but it says error I don't know why. So, can you tell me the reason for that error. And also is there any straight-way for using this (divisibility) operation directly on tuples without converting them to list first.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely entering the numbers with spaces (or commas) in between. Hence, these spaces (or commas) make it into the tuple -- and *can't* be converted into `int`s.

Try instead, using [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20split#str.split) to put the input numbers into a list.

```
def Div3and5():
    c = input("Enter 3 numbers:").split(",")
    # Gives you the list e.g. ["3", "4", "5"]

    m = [int(x) for x in c]
    # Gives you the list e.g. [3, 4, 5]

    for i in m:
        if i % 3 == 0:
           print(f"{i} is divisible by 3")

Div3and5()
```

Remember that `str.split()` will accept a delimiter as an argument. In this case, I've put a comma `,`, but you can have a space `' '` instead, depending on how your input should be entered by the user.

Note also, you were doing `if m[i] % 3 == 0` in the `if` statement instead of `if i % 3 == 0`. This is not correct since `i` in each iteration of the loop *is* an element of the list `m`, and not an index.

Also, your condition `i % 3 == 0` is such that if `i` is divisible by 3, then the `print` should indicate that the number is divisible -- you were printing that it's not divisible (probably a typo).

If you want all the numbers divisible by 3 **and** 5, you can change the condition like this:

```
if i % 3 == 0 and i % 5 == 0:
    print(f"{i} is divisible by 3 and 5")
```

Comment: When I try to enter numbers without commas like 123, it shows shows correct answer before entering for loop, but when i enter like 1,23,4 it shows the above error i mentioned

Comment: And whenever I enter more than one digit number, it splits all of them. So how can I keep them as a single entity?

Comment: Ok @user272837 I've updated the code above to use comma (`,`) as a delimiter for the split instead of the default whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer of your QUESTION :

```
def Div3and5():
c = input("Enter 3 numbers:")

list=c.split(",")
c=tuple(list)

m = [int(x) for x in c]


for i in m:
    if i % 3 == 0:
            print(f'{i} is is divisible by 3')
           

Div3and5()
```

#Enter 3 numbers with "," : 123,45,67